# Drawing a gradient on a path programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, core-animation

I have been trying to draw a gradient on a path similar to how it is done in the image below using either CALayers or CGContexts.

The path does not need to have a variable thickness or outline. It just needs the gradient on the path.

[image: Path Gradient]
<sub>(source: [sethtaylor.com](http://sethtaylor.com/b2/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/illustrator_gradient_on_a_path.jpg))</sub>

I have been using the solution in the following answer [Draw gradient along a curved UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632365/draw-gradient-along-a-curved-uibezierpath) when my line was near straight. Now the line curves back on itself like in the image above and needs the stroke to be drawn along the path programmatically.

I am not quite sure where to start looking for this. What would you try?

Comment: There is no built in support for this. It will be a lot of work.

Comment: How would you go about solving this?

Comment: I'm thinking one could trace the path one pixel at a time and draw a circle, interpolating manually between the colors.

Comment: Another possible approach would be to approximate the curve as arcs ([something like this](http://itc.ktu.lt/itc354/Riskus354.pdf)) and drawing an angular gradient for each arc. I think it could work. I haven't tested it though.

Answer (score 0):

[@saniul on Twitter pointed out](https://twitter.com/saniul/status/593111085407866880) to [Gradient Polyline with MapKit ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682688/gradient-polyline-with-mapkit-ios/20159374#20159374), which has the code for stepping through a path and drawing each segment differently. Should have all the building blocks you need!

Comment: Looks promising, will have a go at this tomorrow!